# Enhanced Binary Search

Tags: binary-search

I am doing interview prep questions and have come across this problem: **Search an element in a sorted and rotated array.**

The most obvious solution to me is to **1)** find the pivot point (where the number is greater than the next number), and **2)** use that as a dividing point to know which half of the rotated and sorted array to execute binary search.

I found a "better" (or so they claim in geeks for geeks) solution. So as to not bore you with code, here is the high level idea. My question is: **I don't understand how finding the middle point let's us search in only one pass.** Is this honestly any better than the initial solution I came up with?

High level "improved/better" approach:

```
1) Find middle point mid = (l + h)/2
2) If key is present at middle point, return mid.
3) Else If arr[l..mid] is sorted
    a) If key to be searched lies in range from arr[l]
       to arr[mid], recur for arr[l..mid].
    b) Else recur for arr[mid+1..r]
4) Else (arr[mid+1..r] must be sorted)
    a) If key to be searched lies in range from arr[mid+1]
       to arr[r], recur for arr[mid+1..r].
    b) Else recur for arr[l..mid]
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort - http://bl.ocks.org/andrewringler/raw/3809399/

Comment: It might help for you to define what you mean by "a sorted and rotated array." Based on a similar question I found online, I think you mean an array that was sorted and has since been rotated. E.g. [4, 5, 1, 2, 3]. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If I understand your solution, it's O(n), since you have to scan the array to find the point of rotation. If you're going to scan the array anyway, you may as well just look for the element while doing that. So your approach is no better than just checking each item one by one.

Comment: The better approach you describe can be found in more detail here: http://articles.leetcode.com/searching-element-in-rotated-array/. Essentially, at each step, you're cutting the input in half, so this solution is O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Your step 1 requires you to find the pivot point.  To do that requires a search.  The solution combines a binary search for the pivot point with a binary search for the target; your solution does not.